# Using mocha-given to test a Meteor package

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

I'm up and running with [practicalmeteor:mocha](https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mocha/) but would like to try [mocha-given](https://github.com/rendro/mocha-given). I think the way to go would be to use the [browser version](https://github.com/rendro/mocha-given/blob/master/browser/mocha-given.js) but I can't get it to work. I added the browser version file and included it in `api.addFiles` but I get `ReferenceError: Given is not defined` when I try to use it.

Comment: if you added it manauly you will also need to do `api.export('OBJECT', ['client', 'server'])` so it can be used outside the package.

Comment: Not trying to use it outside the package. Just trying to test the package with it.

Comment: do you have `Package.onTest`? take a look at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs if you didnt forget anything for the package.js

Comment: Yes. Everything works except when I try to use given.